# Android Twitter Connection and Share Text on Twitter

Tags: android, twitter

I try to make connection with twitter  form this link

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidTwitter

```
    public class TestConnect extends Activity {
private TwitterApp mTwitter;
private CheckBox mTwitterBtn;

private static final String twitter_consumer_key = "xxx";
private static final String twitter_secret_key = "xxx";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mTwitterBtn = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.twitterCheck);

    mTwitterBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onTwitterClick();
        }
    });

    mTwitter    = new TwitterApp(this, twitter_consumer_key,twitter_secret_key);

    mTwitter.setListener(mTwLoginDialogListener);

    if (mTwitter.hasAccessToken()) {
        mTwitterBtn.setChecked(true);

        String username = mTwitter.getUsername();
        username        = (username.equals("")) ? "Unknown" : username;

        mTwitterBtn.setText("  Twitter (" + username + ")");
        mTwitterBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    Button goBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    goBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(TestConnect.this, TestPost.class));
        }
    });
}

private void onTwitterClick() {
    if (mTwitter.hasAccessToken()) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setMessage("Delete current Twitter connection?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       mTwitter.resetAccessToken();

                       mTwitterBtn.setChecked(false);
                       mTwitterBtn.setText("  Twitter (Not connected)");
                       mTwitterBtn.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                        mTwitterBtn.setChecked(true);
                   }
               });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

        alert.show();
    } else {
        mTwitterBtn.setChecked(false);

        mTwitter.authorize();
    }
}

private final TwDialogListener mTwLoginDialogListener = new TwDialogListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String value) {
        String username = mTwitter.getUsername();
        username        = (username.equals("")) ? "No Name" : username;

        mTwitterBtn.setText("  Twitter  (" + username + ")");
        mTwitterBtn.setChecked(true);
        mTwitterBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        Toast.makeText(TestConnect.this, "Connected to Twitter as " + username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String value) {
        mTwitterBtn.setChecked(false);

        Toast.makeText(TestConnect.this, "Twitter connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
   }
```

I have run this app successfully on my device ...
But when i try to connect I get Message  Twitter Connection Fail
And I am  not able to post message

Please help in ... I new to twitter connection with android ...
Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the logcat too

Comment: I didnt get error in logcat .... Just toast appear...Twitter Connection Fail

Comment: Have you set everything in the Twitter developer console properly ?

Comment: Twitter developer console properly  means ....consumer_key and secret_key ? that I have set

Comment: @Yeah you are right.Did you checked for Internet connection and permission ?

Comment: ya... i have done that too... Please help me ... if u have done with twitter connection

Comment: can you tell me what i have set in TestConnect ? 
String username = mTwitter.getUsername();
username=(username.equals("")) ? "Unknown" : username; 
And in TestPost.java 
private String username = "";

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37239/discussion-between-user2012-and-omsai)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this - [TwitterOAuthView](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/TwitterOAuthView)